# Is this the right situation to use a class with all static fields/methods?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an application in Android Studio where practically every activity will in one way or another play a sound that's 1-3 seconds long. The activities will contain square images that will play a sound when touched.

I wrote the code for media playback over and over in all activities, so I figured I can make a separate class that handles the playback instead. Plus I had issues with sounds from different activities playing over each other:

```
public class SoundPlayback {

/** provides access to volume and ringer mode control. */
private static AudioManager audioManager;

/** Handles playback of all the sound files */
// Initialize the MediaPlayer as a global variable
private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

/**
 * The listener gets triggered when the mediaPlayer has completed
 * playing the audio file.
 */
private static MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }
};

/**
 * This listener gets triggered whenever the audio focus changes
 * (i.e., we gain or lose audio focus because of another app or device).
 */
private static AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener audioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT ||
                focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) {
            // The AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT case means that we've lost audio focus for a
            // short amount of time. The AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK case means that
            // our app is allowed to continue playing sound but at a lower volume. We'll treat
            // both cases the same way because our app is playing short sound files.

            // Pause playback and reset player to the start of the file. That way, we can
            // play the word from the beginning when we resume playback.
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
            // The AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS case means we've lost audio focus
            // Stop playback and clean up resources
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
            // The AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN case means we have regained focus and can resume playback.
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
};

public static void initializeManagerService(Context context) {
    // Create and setup the Audio Manager to request audio focus
    audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
}

public static void initializePlayer(Context context, int audioResourceID) {
    // Request audio focus in order to play the audio file. The app needs to play a
    // short audio file, so we will request audio focus with a short amount of time
    // with AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT.
    int result =  audioManager.requestAudioFocus(audioFocusChangeListener,
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

    if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
        // Using the factory method create() we set the audio resource to be played when
        // chosen category is selected.
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, audioResourceID);

        // Stat playback of audio
        mediaPlayer.start();

        // Listen for when the playback has finished
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);

    }
}

/** Clean up the media player by releasing its resources */
public static void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    // If the media player is not null, then it may be currently playing a sound.
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        // Regardless of the current state of the media player, release its resources
        // because we no longer need it.
        mediaPlayer.release();

        // Set the media player back to null. For our code, we've decided that
        // setting the media player to null is an easy way to tell that the media player
        // is not configured to play an audio file at the moment.
        mediaPlayer = null;

        // Regardless of whether or not we were granted audio focus, abandon it. This also
        // unregisters the AudioFocusChangeListener so we don't get anymore callbacks.
        audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(audioFocusChangeListener);
    }
}
```

}

And is called in the onCreate method of the activity as such:

```
    // Store context to be used for calling SoundPlayback
    final Context context = getApplicationContext();

    // Initialize the Audio Manager AUDIO_SERVICE
    SoundPlayback.initializeManagerService(context);

    // Set onItemClickListener to handle opening of categories
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            // Store the current Category object that the CategoryAdapter is iterating, using
            // the ArrayList method get(). Input parameter is int index, which corresponds
            // to the given position the user clicked on.
            Category currentCategory = categories.get(position);

            // Release the media player if it currently exists, because we are about to
            // play a different sound file.
            SoundPlayback.releaseMediaPlayer();

            // Initialize playback of the sound related to the item the user has selected
            SoundPlayback.initializePlayer(context, currentCategory.getAudioResourceID());

    });
```

This solution works perfectly for my application, but it feels somehow like I'm cheating. Is this the right situation to use a class with only static fields and methods? Should I use a singleton instead?

I disregarded using a Service, since the sounds played are only a few seconds long and it feels like the required memory / battery usage would be unnecessary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking to review working code belong on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry, please upvote, I accidentaly posted the question before finishing!

Comment: The point is: we dont do reviews of working code here. There is a specific community for that.

Comment: I suggest you post this in [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @GhostCat Maybe I phrased the question wrongly, I'm not looking for a review of my code. I just want to know if it's possible to use a class this way or if singleton is to be used instead.

Comment: @m0skit0 Thank you, I will try that instead I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but singleton is always a better solution.  It is very difficult to understand this until you have had to live with an all static solution though, so try it and see how it goes for you.

For example, how do you write a unit test for that?

As another example--suppose you had a Notification interface and had many implementations... sound-notifier, shade-notifier, watch-notifier, email-notifier, ...  How do you adapt your static implementation and use it in collections with other "notification" objects?  Not that you want to now, it's just that using all statics is very inflexible making the solution to many problems involve silly adapters and copy/paste solutions.

By the way, a singleton isn't a fantastic idea either, but if you're not using DI it may be the best easy alternative available to you.

Comment: `how do you write a unit test for that?` -- You call the static method, passing values for the parameters, and assert the return value of the call.  If the method modifies an object in-place, pass in a stub or mock object and assert the correct state change on the stub/mock.  Simple.